# Redis wildcard keys on get

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I am working on a python project using redis, after a few researches I didn't find anything that explain how to make a get() on a string containing a wildcard '*'.

So I have a few keys :

```
example.first
example.second
```

I would like to get the keys / values of example.first and example.second :

```
mymap = r_server.hgetall('example.*')
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After reading deeper the documentation, I found this :

```
mymap = r_server.keys(pattern='example.*')
```

If that can help anyone !

Comment: Reading deep is always good, however the Redis `KEYS` command is dangerous (read the [doc](http://redis.io/commands/keys) and should not be used. If needed, [`SCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/scan) is a better alternative, but what you really should be doing is avoiding ad-hoc pattern-based search for key names entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in my case I don't have the choice to use wildcard, but you're right about keys(), I will take a look at SCAN().

Comment: @ItamarHaber Thanks for the link to the doc, where we can read when to use SCAN instead of KEYS. In my case it is perfectly fine to use KEYS, because I know it will never match more than 10 or 20 hashes. So it is not a 'danger' to performance. However, I'd be interested how to use SCAN / HSCAN with a wildcard. Somehow all my trys failed. And it would be a valid answer still missing here.

Comment: The number of keys matching is one worry, the first one is scanning the database and that is related to the total number of keys in the databases not just those matched.

Comment: @anarchist812 the thing to remember about scan is the pattern is matched after the cursor is returned, so you could end up with many empty pages until you find one that has a matching pattern.