# Azure Redis - Key Wildcard using pattern matching?

Tags: c#, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

As the title suggests, I am wondering if there is an efficient way to leverage the SCAN/Pattern. I am using c# .net core. When I search into the IDatabase, I can't really find anything other than SetScan that would allow for a pattern, but this is clearly not the correct thing. This is a bit unusual to me as the redis console in Azure Redis does support the concept of SCAN. [image]

I need to be able to pass a partial key here:

```
     Assume I can store keys like this: "SID_{0}_CID_{1}_OID_{2}_BID_{3}"

     ///BUT when I call Redis, I might only have part of the key
     RedisValue value =      await _redisConnection.BasicRetryAsync(async (db) => await db.StringGetAsync(key)); //<-- key needs to be like '*CID_123*BID_333*' 
         if(value.HasValue)
             return value;
        
         return string.Empty;
```

`db implements IDatabase which implements IRedis and IDatabaseAsync`

Anyone have an idea how I might achieve this? Python guy seems to have this available but I can't find similar.. [Redis wildcard keys on get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332625/redis-wildcard-keys-on-get)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:

```
  public async  Task<RedisValue[]> GetItems(string customPattern)
        {
            var endpoints = _connection.GetEndPoints(); 
            var s= _connection.GetServer(endpoints[0]);
            var keys =  s.Keys(pattern: customPattern).ToArray();
            return await _database.StringGetAsync(keys);
        }
```

to riff the Northern Pikes... 'it ain't pretty it just looks that way.'